# How to insert data from select query when databases are in seperate servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL-Server 2012. 
I want to select some data from a table in db1 on server1 and insert the selected data to table2 in db2 on server2.
I only have read access on db1 on server1 and i have write access on db2 on server2.
Please tell me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a Oracle server I would have used a Database link, if a physical connection between them is possible. Not sure a similar feature is available in SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a linked server object: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx**

You will then be able to use an insert into server2, db2 using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO server2.db2.dbo.table_name (column1, column2) ;
SELECT FROM table_name table_name ;
```

Assumption is that the query would run on server1.